# sanitize gem issue with &lt; and &gt;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitize

I am using the sanitize gem https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize to remove some HTML tags from a string.

However, before sanitizing the string in my controller, the string is being set as follows:

```
<p>This is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; and this <span style="text-decoration: underline;">is</span> &lt;i&gt;italics&lt;/i&gt; ok? This <em>is not </em>a problem.</p>
```

meaning that < and > are being replaced by `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

How can I use the sanitize gem to remove for example  *and*  when these tags are being represented as `&lt;i&gt;` and `&lt;/i&gt;` in the controller?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your english. What is the undesired outcome you're getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the escaped HTML tags (< and >) to be treated as HTML for the purposes of sanitizing, then you'll have to unescape them first:

```
require 'cgi'
Sanitize.clean(CGI.unescapeHTML(your_string))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Richard Hulse. However, I am not encountering another issue: 

Escaped HTML:
    <p>&lt;p&gt;PARAGRAPH&lt;/p&gt;</p>

Unescaped HTML (using CGI.unescapeHTML(escaped_html)):
    <p><p>PARAGRAPH</p></p>

Sanitized HTML (using Sanitize.clean(unescaped_html, :elements => ['a', 'p', 'b', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'strong'])):
    <p></p><p>PARAGRAPH</p>

Any idea why there is a </p> after the opening <p>? I know this may not be valid HTML, but I wish to keep the order of the tags.

Thanks

Comment: The Sanitize Gem is built on top of Nokogiri, which means that it will close any unclosed tags automatically. The first <p> is seen as an unclosed tag. The last extra closing tag is seen as redundant. If you need to handle HTML that does not validate you are probably going to have to write your own parser (which is not a task to be taken lightly). :-)

Comment: Maybe @Richard Hulse can help me with another sanitize-related issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405189/no-such-file-to-load-sanitize-loaderror Thanks

Comment: Sure. If this is the correct answer can you please mark it as so.