# no such file to load -- sanitize (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, sanitize

(Working in Ubuntu and using ruby, rails, and gems.)

I installed the sanitize gem (version 2.0.3).

When requiring it from the code, an error is occurring:

`require': no such file to load -- sanitize (LoadError)

I know the gem is installed:
    gem list | grep sanitize 
returns
sanitize (2.0.3)

```
which gem
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/gem
```

and

```
which ruby
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

So to check which gem is installed

```
ls -l /usr/bin/gem*
```

returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 2011-12-06 18:37 /usr/bin/gem -> /usr/bin/gem1.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 545 2011-09-16 16:19 /usr/bin/gem1.8
```

And to check which ruby version is installed

```
ls -l /usr/bin/ruby*
```

returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 2011-12-06 18:38 /usr/bin/ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6264 2010-03-19 17:52 /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Finally,

```
gem env
```

returns

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I read elsewhere on stackoverflow that this can be solved by symbolic links. I also read about using the config/environment.rb file, but I prefer to fix it with symbolic links.

Any idea which links I have to create or change?

UPDATE: 
    require 'nokogiri'
is also return the no such file to load error. I have nokogiri (1.5.0) installed.

Thanks

Comment: You are referencing Sanitize somewhere in the Rails code?

Comment: @RichardHulse Only calling it in a controller. But even if I do a new file (e.g. file.rb) with just "require 'sanitize'" and execute it "ruby file.rb" I get the error no such file to load -- sanitize (LoadError)

Comment: @Richard Hulse  
When I run echo $PATH I get the following:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8:/usr/bin/ruby:/var/lib/gems/1.8/:/root/.gem/ruby/1.8/:/usr/bin/gem:/usr/bin/gem:/usr/bin/ruby

Comment: @Richard Hulse require nokogiri is also giving the same problem. I have nokogiri (1.5.0) installed.

Comment: @RichardHulse Fixed: have to add require 'rubygems' at the top of the file.  Thanks